# iOS - Synchronize Web and App Subscription

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

How can we synchronize web subscription with iOS In-App subscription.

i.e Lets say if i am using in-app purchase on iOS, but the user subscribes from the web using stripe payment. How can i handle this subscription scenario for my iOS app ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to maintain that in your database(web-Service) , where you can store necessary information like : userid , subscriptionId, number of days when subscription is active , etc.  You need to check subscription status at the time when user logs in.

Comment: Thanks Nilomi. So once the user pays from the web i basically block the pay button from in-app unless the subscription expires right.

Comment: @Puneeth exactly

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a parameter in web service call that indicates whether the user has bought the subscription from web or not for e.g "isSubscriptionValid".

Depending on this parameter's value you can control the features in your app. Make sure you keep a check on the subscription from your server end when the subscription expires if your subscription type is renewable.

Also, you should receive this parameter's value every time the app is launched. So select your API carefully so that your app remains in sync with web.

Comment: Thanks Ritu. So once the user pays from the web i basically block the pay button from in-app unless the subscription expires right.

Comment: Yes, else you can just simply hide the button also. Your call. ;)